# Addressing OLE Object in ppt through excel sometimes returns run-time error 430

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have an Excel workbook which creates a summary in ppt. It has been mainly coded by somebody else which I cannot reach out to anymore. Thus, I hope you guys can help me. It basically creates 3 different types of slides 5 times each. And the last type (from now on type_3) is creating issues. It basically takes a range of cells from a sheet called "powerpoint feeder" and copies that range to a powerpoint slide as an OLE object. Afterwards, I need to clean some cells in there. To make the text in some other cells overflow (= readable) because I cannot adjust the column width due to limited space on those slides. Now, sometimes running the code provides me with a run-time error 430: 'class does not support automation or does not support expected interface'. Debugger directs me to the specific line marked in the code below. The error does not occur, if I open the excel, type in my data, and then run it (no other powerpoint and excel open). If I run it again afterwards, it generates the aforementioned error. Closing all Excels and powerpoints, then reopening the excel, and running the code again will work however. I am assuming, I am not properly addressing the OLE Object as I have never worked with it before.

Bonus question: I seemingly insert the entire excel in each of my 5 Type_3 slides' OLE Objects,  making my 20 slide ppt over 8 MBs large (1 Excel = roughly 1.6 MBs). I do not need all this necessarily. However, it is important that later adjustments can be made to the table in the powerpoint (but not necessarily in excel/the entire workbook).

Help would be much appreciated! I hope, I made my point clear.

```
Sub Type_3(i_Anchor As Range, i_Title As String, index As Integer)
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range    


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Powerpoint feeder").Activate
Set rng = i_Anchor
num_columns = 8

With Sheets("Powerpoint feeder")     'Determine range
    test_cell = rng.Value
    i = 1
    Do While test_cell <> ""
        i = i + 1
        test_cell = .Cells(rng.Row + i, rng.Column)
    Loop

    num_rows = i - 1

    .Range(.Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column), .Cells(rng.Row + num_rows - 1, rng.Column + num_columns - 1)).Copy
End With

Position = 1 'Determine the position of the slide

For i = 0 To index - 1
    Position = Position + Type_1_index(i) + Type_2_index(i)
Next i

Position = Position + 1

Position = Position + Num_Type_3

Set New_slide = myPresentation.Slides.AddSlide(Position, myPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(7))   'Create new slide

With New_slide
    .Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse  'Create Table

    Set New_Table = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)   'Set position in slide
    New_Table.Left = 30
    New_Table.Top = 95
    New_Table.Width = 660

   '****Next line produces error****     

With New_Table.OLEFormat.Object.Sheets("Powerpoint feeder")     
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column), .Cells(rng.Row + num_rows - 1, rng.Column))
            For Each cel In rng
                If Left(cel.Value, 1) = "A" Then
                    For x = 1 To 5
                        cel.Offset(0, x).ClearContents 'Enables headline overflow to adjacent empty cells
                    Next x
                End If
            Next cel
        End With

End With

Num_Type_3 = Num_Type_3 + 1

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

With the help of @Domenic, I was able to create the table without a link to excel cutting down the size to a tenth of the initial size. Great! And also made the readability of the headlines work with the code below. However, the code only works if I "walk" through it, but not when I run through it. Every time, I run through it, I get the *run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'Table' of object 'Shape' failed.* I tried adding `Application.Wait` before the error. I tried `On Error Resume Next` and I tried `DoEvents`. Nothing would make it work. Any suggestions?

```
`With New_slide
myPresentation.Windows(1).Activate
myPresentation.Windows(1).View.GotoSlide Position
.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"

Set New_Table = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
    New_Table.Left = 30
    New_Table.Top = 95
    New_Table.Width = 660

        With New_Table.Table    '****ERROR OCCURS HERE****
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                If Left(.Cell(iRow, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, 1)= "A" Then
                   For iCol = 2 To 4
                        .Cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ""
                   Next iCol
                   .Cell(iRow, 1).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(iRow, 4)
                   .Rows(iRow).Height = 13.04 'Point equivalent of standard rows with a height of 0.46 cm
                End If
            Next iRow
        End With`
```

**EDIT 2:**

Solution was provided by Domenic. It was sufficient to add this delay right after pasting only not slowing down the code too much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

The fact that you don't get an error when stepping through the code suggests that more time may be needed before the object can be pasted.  We can try calling another procedure that will delay the process for a few seconds, while at the same time calling the DoEvents function.  Therefore, first copy the following macro into your module...

```
Sub Delay(Optional ByVal Secs As Integer = 3)
     Dim sngStartTime As Single
     sngStartTime = Timer
     Do Until Timer > sngStartTime + Secs
         DoEvents
     Loop
End Sub
```

Then, in your original code, call the macro right after you copy your range...

```
Delay
```

By default, your macro will automatically be delayed by 3 seconds.  You can delay it for a little longer, if needed.  For example, to delay it by 5 seconds, you can call it like this...

```
Delay 5
```

Also, it may help to call Delay right after pasting as well.

**End of edit** ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

First, change the DataType argument for PasteSpecial to `ppPasteHTML`...

```
.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse  'Create Table
```

Then, change your `With/End With` statement as follows...

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

With New_Table.Table
    For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        If Left(.cell(iRow, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, 1) = "A" Then
            For iCol = 2 To .Columns.Count
                .cell(iRow, iCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ""
            Next iCol
        End If
    Next iRow
End With
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. changing `ppPasteOLEObject` to `ppPasteShape` returns run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)': Shapes.PasteSpecial : invalid request. the specified data type is unavailable.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been ppPasteHTML.  I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for getting back at me! Yet, I am afraid that still does not solve the problem. Same runtime error. However, this time it says after the invalid request: "Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here."

Comment: Does it help if you add `DoEvents` before and after pasting?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't change a thing unfortunately

Comment: I was able to make it partially work with some adjustments of you, Thanks for that. Do you have a clue on my edits too?

Comment: Thank you so much! How this was any different from what I tried, but it was! You made my day! Can you maybe elaborate a little on why this happens and when?

Comment: That's great, I'm glad it's working for you.  While `DoEvents` allows the operating system to process other events, the 3 second delay allows Windows time to finish copying the object to the clipboard.